# React-native fetch upload file and message with formdata, server doesnt get file, but still get message and id

Tags: react-native, file-upload, fetch, form-data

Im get a file with react-native-document-picker [that object i get from file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DiMKH.png)
then i do formData =>

`let filesToSend = new FormData(); filesToSend.append('Claim_ID', ID); filesToSend.append('Message', message); filesToSend.append('MainFiles', files);`

[in fetch response i get nothing, if i console.log whole fetch, i will get Network request error, but server still get my request with id and message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnHZP.png)
i have no idea what is going wrong

Answer (score 0):

Im solved it with update Flipper